# Pigeonhole Principle: Among any seven integers, there must be two whose sum or difference is divisible by $10$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

So, I am studying computer science (bachelor). This is actually my third degree (bachelor and master in management previously). I'm new to discrete mathematics, but I find as useful as fascinating.(I often stay late at night studying it).

So one of the exercises we're doing involves the Pigeonhole Principle. I'm asked to prove with the help of the Pigeonhole Principle that in any set of seven natural numbers, there is always a pair of numbers whose sum or difference is a multiple of 10.

I used Java to generate a set of random numbers:
A = {53, 44, 34, 111, 134, 564, 1}.

If we look closely at what the exercise is asking, we see that there's a universal statement. It's identified by the keyword "always". This means that my random set should match the x R y criteria.

And indeed, if we take 111 - 1 = 110, we get a multiple of 10, because 110/10 = 11. I tried this with other sets, and the principle holds.

I would like to know if the way I've formulated the solution is correct. In this case, I want to know if if I've identified the "pigeonholes" and "pigeons" correctly.

So, here's the solution formulation:

The x R y relation determines the number of pigeonholes. In this case, the relation specifies that there's at least a single pair which matches the universal statement mentioned earlier. This means that if we have 7 elements in the set, but one pair, we have 6 pigeonholes. This allows us to put 7 element in one of the boxes, with the remaining extra element into the same box (in this case, 111 and 1).

Let me know what you think, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  If you have two numbers with the same remainder when divided by $10$, then their difference is divisible by $10$, so you are done.  Otherwise, consider the six pigeonholes (remainders when divided by $10$) $\{0\}, \{1, 9\}, \{2, 8\}, \{3, 7\}, \{4, 6\}, \{5\}$.  Since you have seven numbers, two of them must be in the same pigeonhole.  What can you conclude?

Comment: If we have seven numbers, and two of them are in the same pigeonhole, then it stands to reason that the principle holds, i.e., we have more pigeons than pigeonholes, therefore two are in the same pigeonhole. Thus, there's at least a pair that matches the criteria.

Comment: @Endris Specifically, what conclusion can you draw if two of the numbers are in the same pigeonhole?  That must be part of your argument.

Comment: Given the conditions, and given the observations (i.e., two of the numbers are in the same pigeonhole), in a set of seven natural numbers, there is always at least one pair whose sum or difference is a multiple of 10.

Comment: Almost.  Notice that we have already addressed the difference condition in the first sentence.  If two numbers are in the same pigeonhole, then their sum must be divisible by $10$.

Comment: Hmmm. The only other conclusion that I can come up with right now is that the relation is not one-to-one (it cannot be given the circumstances). However, this seems only to describe the relations from a different perspective. 

From the hint above, I can observe that there are 4 pairs that, when added, output 10, except for 0 and 5. But the set requires seven natural numbers. Zero is part of whole/integer numbers. Hmmm.

Comment: Notice that if you have two numbers with remainder $0$ or two numbers with remainder $5$ when divided by $10$, their sum is divisible by $10$ (as is their difference).